# Changing a UIView to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, nib

When I change a `UIView` to `UIScrollView` in my nib, it doesn't change to show the `UIScrollView` parameters. When I run, it crashes saying cannot find class MYPROJECTNAME_Scrollview.

Why can't I change this in the nib?

Comment: if you have create any IBOutlet for the view did you update it to UIScrollview? where you don't get property change in nib or programatically?

Comment: Stop using nibs, programmatically create your views

Comment: @Pyro I updated the outlet and it linked fine, yes. Loxx, Apple continues to add support for storyboard and auto-layout constraints for nib.